# Meaning of word "iteration" or expression "do twenty iterations" or "first iteration"

Tags: numerical-methods

This has bothered me for a long time. Basically, an iteration is a repetition.

Suppose I have to do Newtons method for some function and have an initial abscissa $x_0$. I've been asked to do 20 iterations. Will $x_1$ (calculated using the iterative formula) count as my first iteration? I haven't done any repetitions yet so I think it shouldn't... But this isn't the way it is used. People refer to $X$ iterations in Newton's method as $X$ new abscissas calculated using the iterative formula.

As another example suppose I'm programming the false-position method. Then each iteration is each abscissa calculated that crosses the x-axis. Right?

I guess my question really boils down to: Which is the first iteration? Why would some programmers refer to the "zeroth iteration"?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say $x_1$ is your first repetition, even if you haven't repeated anything yet. Note that if you go to the gym and do "20 reps", you do 20 sit-ups (or whatever), not "do one, then repeat 20 times".

Comment: The ordinary mathematical meaning is clear:  We do it $20$ times.  Maybe that is inconsistent with a grammarian's interpretation.  No big deal, since real people don't talk that way. Hard to imagine a carpenter saying to an apprentice I want you to do $20$  iterations of hitting that nail. Unless perhaps the carpenter is a PhD in math, trying to earn a living.

Comment: lol. I know a maths prof who is also a carpenter ;)

Comment: Should I delete this question?